# Use Class From File In Different Folder

Tags: swift, xcode

In Xcode, I have a folder called DataStore with a file called RequestDataStore.swift in it that declares a class also called RequestDataStore. I have another folder called Requests and I am trying to access the RequestDataStore class I made in the other folder like this:

```
let requestDataStore = RequestDataStore()
```

but Xcode throws the error `Use of unresolved identifier 'RequestDataStore'`. It is failing to find that file and I noticed that I am able to reference files that same way as long as they are in the same folder. How can I make Xcode be aware of the RequestDataStore.swift file?

Comment: Did you make sure to enable target membership for the RequestDataStore.swift file? You can do so in the File Inspector on the right.

Comment: In answer to your question, no, they don’t need to be in the same folder. They need to be members of the same target within your project. Or if the `RequestDataStore` is in another target (e.g. a pod or framework target), then you might need to `import` the appropriate framework. We can’t answer your question why it’s not working in your case without knowing more about how the project is configured, what sources are included, what frameworks you’re using, etc.

Comment: @Rob good point, sorry about that. Yes, the two files are in different targets. The file in the `Requests` folder is a Siri `Intents Extension`. I have tried adding the target in the file explorer but that causes the imports in `RequestDataStore.swift` to throw errors. Can you elaborate on how to import the frameworks like you mentioned?

Comment: If it’s a separate target, you generally would not add the sources to your current target, but rather the source file that is trying to use `RequestDataStore` would just have a `import MyAppKit` where the `MyAppKit` would be the name of the target in which `RequestDataStore` is defined.

Answer (score 2):

If the file `RequestDataStore.swift` is in your project, having the file opened in Xcode, you should see on the **File Inspector** no the right (you can open it pressing option + command + 1 `⌘ ⌥ 1`).

There you have to see in the **Target Membership** you have checked the name of the Xcode project, so your app can get that file and use it in your complete code.

Hope this is what you need.